# How to copy paste a table from Excel sheet to outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a dynamic table in sheet2 of my Excel sheet.
How to copy this entire table from sheet2 to outlook mail body using Outlook VBA.

Comment: Can you share an example spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

***The below steps you have to follow,***

```
      Copy the tables into Microsoft word application
      Now Copy the tables from Microsoft word application
      Now Past the copied tables from Microsoft word application to your Email
```

***This will work perfectly, let me know via comments if you are still facing the issue.***

Comment: this is a nice trick, Excel to Word to Outlook, Totally Microsoft Style. I wish they could learn something from Apple. But, it takes years. oh, wait, it's 2018 already...

Answer (score 0):

1. Select First Cell of your table, means first header cell
2. Press Ctrl+A
3. Press Ctrl+C
4. Switch to Outlook
5. Place the Cursor in your Email Body where you want table
6. Press Ctrl+V

Answer (score -1):

(1) Ctrl+A in your excel then (2) Ctrl+C  and (3) Ctrl+V in outlook